# pip install tensorflow not working for me

Tags: python-3.x, windows, tensorflow, pip, python-venv

using a new venv in VSCode on Windows 10 and wanted to install matplotlib and tensorflow matplotlib installed succesfyllu however tensorflow did not also tried using a specific version but that did not help either

```
(.venv) PS D:\PY_Projects\Test> **pip install matplotlib**
Collecting matplotlib
  Using cached matplotlib-3.8.2-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata (5.9 kB)
Collecting contourpy>=1.0.1 (from matplotlib)
  Using cached contourpy-1.2.0-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata (5.8 kB)
Collecting cycler>=0.10 (from matplotlib)
....
....
Installing collected packages: six, pyparsing, pillow, packaging, numpy, kiwisolver, fonttools, cycler,   python-dateutil, contourpy, matplotlib
Successfully installed contourpy-1.2.0 cycler-0.12.1 fonttools-4.47.0 kiwisolver-1.4.5 matplotlib-3.8.2 numpy-1.26.3 packaging-23.2 pillow-10.2.0 pyparsing-3.1.1 python-dateutil-2.8.2 six-1.16.0
(.venv) PS D:\PY_Projects\Test> **pip install tensorflow**
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow
(.venv) PS D:\PY_Projects\Test> **pip install tensorflow==2.14.0**
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.14.0 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.14.0
```

Would expect similar behavior when installing packages.
Anyone an idea what could be wrong

Comment: Can you try upgrading pip? `pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: what's your python version?

Comment: You probably have Python 3.12, many packages are not ready for that version, so use 3.11

Comment: Yep I have python version 3.12 just discovered that tensorflow is not supported for version 3.12 yet

Answer (score 0):

[tensorflow](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/)  currently supports Python 3.9 - 3.11. If you don't have any of the supported versions, You can download / install it from https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/. **Do not have Python add itself to PATH as it can really confuse things**.

After installing a supported version on your machine, you can create a virtual environment. For example, you can create a python 3.11 virtual environment using `python3.11 -m venv env/place/you/want/to/save/to`, activate your venv and then install tensorflow using `python -m pip install tensorflow`.